# How to force cellTable to show all data (GWT)?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Here I have `itemDetailTable`

```
CellTable<List<String>> itemDetailTable = new CellTable<List<String>>();
ListDataProvider<List<String>> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<List<String>>();
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(itemDetailTable);
final ScrollPanel itemDetailScrollPanel=new ScrollPanel();
FlowPanel itemDetailFlowPanel=new FlowPanel();
itemDetailFlowPanel.add(itemDetailTable);
itemDetailScrollPanel.add(itemDetailFlowPanel);
```

Now my `List<List<String>>` has 16 rows, however, after ran it showed the table with **15 rows** only. If I want to see the row 16 then need to click on the last cell of the table (the cell in the bottom right handside of the table) & enter arrow-down key then it will show the **record 16**.

If i use Simplepager

`SimplePager itemDetailPager = new SimplePager();
itemDetailPager.setDisplay(itemDetailTable);`

then it will have 2 page, the 1st page has 15 records and the 2nd page has 1 record.

That is not OK as I want the table to show all the records at once and won't hide any records.

Someone said that maybe cos I use `List<String>` & that is causing the problem, but I am not sure if that is the main cause.

But If I only has 14 records, then it showed **all 14 records** without any problem.

SO How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try any one

Just pass page size while constructing [CellTable](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html#CellTable%28int%29) that constructs a table with the given page size.

```
int pageSize=16;
CellTable<List<String>> itemDetailTable = new CellTable<List<String>>(pageSize);
```

---

use [CellTable#setPageSize()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#setPageSize%28int%29) to set the number of rows per page and refresh the view.

```
CellTable<List<String>> itemDetailTable = new CellTable<List<String>>();
itemDetailTable.setPageSize(16);
```

---

**Note:** use `GWT.create()` to construct the `SimplePager.Resources` object with as shown below:

```
SimplePager.Resources pagerResources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
// pass the parameters as per your requirement
SimplePager pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pagerResources, false, 0, true);
```

Comment: can we do it dynamically? pagesize is dynamic, not fixed

Comment: call method `setPageSize()` dynamically *that will set the number of rows per page and will refresh the view.*

Comment: setPageZie(int)?  there is not setPageSize() but setPageSize(int)

Comment: or setPageSize(dataList.size());? is ok>

Comment: It's OK but let me check it for 1000 records in that case a vertical scroll bar must come into picture.

Comment: Set a fixed height of `ScrollPanel` to show the vertical scroll bar if no of records is very large.

Comment: if setting fixed height then it will break my GUI, anyway Item details are max about 100 rows, so that will be fine. Thax you for your help